# How to identify blow up algebra away from origin is isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

This is related to Ueno, Algebraic Geometry 2, Example 5.28 of Chpt 5.

Let $R=k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$. Let $I=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$. Form blow up algebra $S=R\oplus I\oplus I^2\oplus\dots$ which is graded $R$ algebra. There is canonical $R\to S$ embedding into $0-$th degree component. This induces $\pi: Proj(S)\to Spec(R)$ map. Consider $U=Spec(R)-\{(0,\dots, 0)\}$. I will denote $S$ as the associated sheaf of $S$ as $O_X$ algebra where $X=Spec(R)$.

The book says $S|_U\cong\oplus_d O_U^{\otimes d}=O_U[T]$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why $S|_U\cong\oplus_d O_U^{\otimes d}=O_U[T]$ is obvious? I could not see this totally obvious unless I pick $U=D(x_i)\subset Spec(R)$ which covers $U$. Hence I see isomorphism easily as all $I|_{D(x_i)}=R_{x_i}$. It seems there is some mechanism that the book sees this obvious as there is no indication for the implication.

Comment: Your argument is short, clear, and correct. What else do you want?

Comment: @KReiser Sometime I feel the book is using some global argument without necessity of observing local behavior though for sheaf exact sequence. I am just wondering whether it is possible to stare at $S|_U$ and $O_U[T]$ and conclude right away, "Aha, they have to be canonically isomorphic" without tediously checking local part or stalk part.